# two action methods for one view -- asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need two action methods for one view

One action method name is "LogOn" and other action method name is "re".
And the view name is LogOn.

I need same display but functionality is different.

One action method is for login and other action method is for registration and the page is one.

So there are two functionalities and both UI are on same view.

How can I accomplish this since I am new to MVC

Comment: Do you have different UI elements for LogOn and Registration?

Comment: yes different UI elements for login and registration but view is one

Comment: In that case you should have two different views. The point of MVC is to separate that kind of thing.

Comment: @Steve So you are saying that I can't put two different functionalities on one view. Then how SO accomplish this: you can answer the question and post comments on one view since SO is created using MVC?

Comment: Not clear why you would do this (IMHO a poor UI and a user only ever registers once so why show a registration form every time thay go to log in), but you need 2 form elements in the view. You could use `@Html.Action()` to call `[ChildActionOnly]` methods that return partial views of a login form and a register form

Comment: @Alex in SO's case I would imagine the question page is one view and when posting an answer or comment, it is sent to the server via an Ajax request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want one page and two functionality like facebook and many other websites. Can you please explain what do u mean by partial views in answer?

Comment: @Steve Thanks Steve. That is helpful. So you are saying, just to confirm, that only one submit control is possible per view?

Comment: @Alex, you can only have one form post on a view, but if you use Ajax you can post (or get) any number to the controller.

Comment: @Steve, Your can have a thousand forms in a view if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view needs to have 2 forms, one for registering and one for login. There are numerous ways to handle this, including a single view model containing properties for the LogInModel and RegisterModel, using `@Html.Action()` to call `[ChildActionOnly]` methods that return partial views or using `@Html.Partial()` to return partial views. For example, create 2 partial views

_Login.cshtml

```
@model yourAssembly.LoginModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account"))
{
  .... // login controls
  <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
}
```

_Register.cshtml

```
@model yourAssembly.RegisterModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
{
  .... // register controls
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

and then in the man view

```
@Html.Partial("_Login", new LogInModel()) // renders the login form
@Html.Partial("_Register", new RegisterModel()) // renders the registration form
```

Comment: As a side note, you should consider wrapping these forms in a hidden `<div>` and then have 2 buttons that display the corresponding form on the view using javascrpt/jquery (seeing 2 forms would be a confusing UI). And ideally the "Register" button would use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial containing the "Register" form since for each user, they will only ever need to do it once (no point sending a whole lot of extra html to the client each time a registered user needs to log on)

Comment: I have added partial view to my parent view. In partial view I am sending data to controller of that view, But it's NOT working. any help please

Comment: How can I possibly tell what mistakes you have made in your code if I cant see it. You need to ask a new question and include the relevant code and clearly explain what you are expecting and what is actually happening (so it does not get closed like this one)

Comment: I have posted a question. here it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325182/partial-view-inside-parent-view-not-sending-data-to-controller-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have separate views for each action, however, what you describe is possible.

One way to do it would be using the viewbag to set which partial view should be displayed.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 ViewBag.ActionType = "Register"
 if(LOGIC THAT DETERMINES LOGIN){
  ViewBag.ActionType = "Login"
 }
 // .. Any additional logic
 return View();
}
```

Then in the View:

```
@* Assuming these are the only options *@
@if(ViewBag.ActionType == "Register"){
 @Html.Partial("_Register")
}else{
 @Html.Partial("_Login")
}
```

Again this is going against MVC as the View should not really contain logic, but the above sends a message to the view which determines which partial view to display. This will still require the Views be separated into their own partial views (`_Login.cshtml` and `_Register.cshtml`) which contain their specific forms.
But will allow a user to navigate one URL and get displayed potentially two different forms.