# Partial view inside parent view not sending data to controller - asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view name test/index

following is the code -

```
@model MyFirstMVC.Models.testModels
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
     @Html.TextBox("test1")
     <input type="submit" value="click" />
     @ViewBag.a
}
```

And the controller of this partial view is following -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyFirstMVC.Models.testModels m)
    {
        ViewBag.a = Request["test1"].ToString() + " from controler";
        return View(m);
    }
```

In my parent view I am embedding my partial view like below -

```
 @Html.Partial("../test/index",new MyFirstMVC.Models.testModels())
```

When I run the application, the partial view do appear in the parent view. But when I enter value inside partial view and submit then nothing is happening (the value is not forwarding to the controller of partial view - I have checked that the controller action method related to the partial view is not invoking either by setting break-point).

Any help will be appreciated. Why my partial view is not sending value to its controller?

Comment: What page do you embedd your partial view?

Comment: Please show the code of your main view

Comment: Is the page renedered at `Controller/Index`? If you leave `Html.BeginForm()` empty, MVC will try to post it to the current URL.
And the values are not passed in `Request` they are passed in a `FormCollection`. Add the FormCollection to your `Index` Method and you will have Access to all form elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the controller and action names in `Html.BeginForm()` if your not posting back to the same method that generated the view

```
@model MyFirstMVC.Models.testModels
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test"))
{ 
    @Html.TextBox("test1")
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
    @ViewBag.a
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick post. But is it possible if I stay on the same page(view) and still able to update the content. I do not want the url change or redirection to partial view. I want to stay on the parent view and still able to trigger action method of child view

Comment: Then you will need to either (1) post the form using ajax or (2) post normally then redirect back to the original method that generated the view. But its not clear exactly what your code is trying to do. Why doesn't your view include any form controls bound to properties of your model and why is the only form control not bound to anything? (or have you just omitted some code because as it is, it make little sense)